# Permutations of numbers with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can one write the numbers ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}$ in a row so that given any number in the row, all of its divisors (not including itself) appear to its left?

I know $1$ has to be the first element, so we only concern ourselves with ordering the numbers $2$ to $6$. $5$ can be anywhere except the first position. We order ${2, 3, 4, 6}$ then multiply that by five (for the five positions we can insert $5$ into afterwards).

Is this correct? And can anyone help me solve the rest? I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about "topological sorting": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20topological,before%20v%20in%20the%20ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're on right track.

We have two base cases ${2,4,6}$ and ${2,6,4}$ :

- ${2,4,6}$

Here $3$ can go in $3$ places. $5$ follows in $5$ spaces.

- ${2,6,4}$

Here $3$ can go in $2$ places. $5$ follows in $5$ spaces.

Total ways $= \boxed{25}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's place $1, 2, 6$ first which can be done in just one way.

Now, $4$ can be placed in $2$ ways -

i) either in between $2, 6$ - then $3$ can be placed in $3$ ways (before $6$).

ii) after $6$ - then $3$ can be placed in $2$ ways (before $6$).

$5$ can always be placed in $5$ ways (any place after $1$).

So total number of ways = $(3 + 2) \times 5 = 25$.